# Change attribute value for event only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this basic form:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    var form = document.getElementById('form');
    form.setAttribute('action', 'export.php');
    form.submit()
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="get.php" id="form">
  <div>
    <label for="date">From</label>
    <input type="date" name="from-date" id="date" />
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="date">To</label>
    <input type="date" name="to-date" id="date" />
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="flags[new]" /> New
    <input type="checkbox" name="flags[updated]" /> Updated
    <input type="checkbox" name="flags[existing]" /> Existing
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="submit" />
  </div>

  <div>
    <button type="button" id="btn">
      <span>Export</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

This works as (near) expected. However, I then clicked on the submit input and it tried going to `export.php`. For some reason my brain was telling me that this is incorrect behaviour, but I get that I've changed the attribute value within the DOM and thus, anything post-clicking the export button will render the attribute value (until I refresh).

I'm aware that I can do another event handler to reset the attribute value, but I feel like that's counter-intuitive, is there something in JS/jQuery that allows me to "toggle" an attribute for the event only? Or do I have to make-do with a hard reset?

**TL;DR**

Is there a way to temporarily set an attribute within an event?

Comment: You either have to reset the action attribute value again, or do the submit manually using JQuery.ajax() . Which one of the two buttons you want to submit manually ( or both ) is up to you.

Comment: @Shilly ah so there's no temp setting attributes? I just have to make do with resets/manual?

Comment: No temp settings afaik. Default form behaviour is submitting to the action attribute on submit click. When JQuery was still needed, people would almost always do the submits manually through $.ajax() and omit the action attribute. You could also like, have the server return the full page again as the response to the post request so it gets reloaded automatically, but that might depend on the rest of what the page does.

Comment: @Shilly dang, I think I'll just settle for resets then :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    let form = document.getElementById('form');

    //Save the current attr
    let currentAttr = form.getAttribute('action');

    form.setAttribute('action', 'export.php');
    form.submit();

    //Reset the previous attr
    form.setAttribute('action', currentAttr);
  })
})
```

You actually save the current attr, submit the form and then set the attribute to the original one.

Hope it solved your issue!

Comment: this is actually literally what I've just done in my code! haha great minds ;)

Comment: Awesome! I think there might be a cleaner way, but haven't figured out anything so far! I'll let you know if something comes out! :)